# iOs OpenGL ES 2.0 adding textures with low opacity on device and on simulator

Tags: ios, opengl-es-2.0, render-to-texture

I have a problem with multiple drawing of textures in my program.

Blending mode is

```
glBlendFuncSeparate(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
glBlendEquation(GL_FUNC_ADD);
```

The value of a-channel is passed into the shader from cpu-code.

```
precision highp float;

uniform sampler2D tShape;

uniform vec4      vColor;
uniform float     sOpacity;

varying vec4 texCoords;\n"

void main() {
    float a = texture2D(tShape, texCoords.xy).x * sOpacity;
    gl_FragColor = vec4(vColor.rgb, a);
}
```

It's calculated previously with

```
O = pow(O, 1.3);
```

for the best visual effect.

I draw with color (0; 0; 0) on the black transparent canvas (0;0;0;0), but with very low opacity:

```
0.03 -> 0.01048
0.06 -> 0.0258
0.09 -> 0.0437
0.12 -> 0.0635
...
```

I expect, that maximal value of point's color will be (0;0;0;1) (black, no transparent) after multiple drawings as on the simulator: 
[image]

but it isn't so on the device:
[image]

Do you have any ideas, why is it so?

**UPDATE:**

Also manual blending works incorrect too (and with difference from standard).

```
glBlendFunc(GL_ONE, GL_ZERO);
```

Fragment shader code:

```
#extension GL_EXT_shader_framebuffer_fetch : require
precision highp float;

uniform sampler2D tShape;

uniform vec4      vColor;
uniform float     sOpacity;

varying vec4 texCoords;

void main() {
    float a = texture2D(tShape, texCoords.xy).x * sOpacity;
    gl_FragColor = vec4(vColor.rgb * a, a) + (gl_LastFragData[0] * (1.0 - a));
}
```

Result on the simulator:
[image]

Result on the device:
[image]

Comment: Can you post your whole fragment shader? It may be some rounding problem.

Comment: Updated (add fragment shader code)

Comment: Rather strange, can you do manual blending and output 0 when certain threshold is met? Just to be sure the problem is not at the shader your input data. Output image should be black at certain areas.

Comment: Shader and input datas are identical on the device and simulator, but results are difference. I think, that the problem is in the device's features or OpenGL driver (rounding values). This explains incorrect work on the device and correct on the simulator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some experiments I've understood, that this problem is in supported precision of device . So on the iPad Air this problem appears less than on iPad 4, 3.

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to understand your approach so I wrote down some equations:

This is how a new drawing is performed (If didn't make any mistake):

```
color = {pencil_shape}*sourceAlpha + {old_paint}*(1-sourceAlpha)
alpha = {pencil_shape} + {old_paint}*(1-sourceAlpha)
```

So basically you alpha is getting closer to 1 on each frame, and you color is blended each time based on the src alpha in the *pencil_shape*.

Questions:

- Do you intend to use the alpha in the output image for anything?
- Is your *pencil_shape* all black (0, 0, 0, 0)? (besides the cornes where I suppose it has some antialiasing effect)

Comment: 1 - Yes, alpha may be used in the output image  in future.
2 - *pencil_shape* is 1-channel image with black (0) background and no black (>0) shape pixels.

Comment: srcAlpha = paramAlpha*{pencil_shape};   
color = paramColor*srcAlpha + {old_paint}*(1-srcAlpha);   
alpha = srcAlpha + {old_paint}*(1-srcAlpha);